# Select only the texts not the whole line in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter.text

I'm trying to select only the entered words in a ScrolledText but the whole line is getting selected. 
Select all code:

```
# I'm using ScrolledText for the input field
self.textBox = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(master=self.topFrame, wrap="word", bg='beige', padx=20, pady=5)

# Binding Shortcuts
rootone.bind("<Control-a>", self.selectAllOperation)

# Function Defination
def selectAllOperation(self, event=None):
        self.textBox.tag_add('sel', '1.0', 'end')
```

This is whats happening,
[image]

This is what I want to do,
[image]

Note that in the second picture only end of the words are selected but in the first picture the whole line is getting selected.
Is it possible in tkinter to implement this feature?

I'm using python 3.6

Answer (score 2):

> **Question**: Select only the texts not the whole line

Instead of selecting the whole text from `1.0` to `end`, you have to do it line by line from `y.0` to `y.end`.

[image]

- [The Tkinter Text Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)
- [How to calculate the height of a dynamic string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45618330/7414759)

---

1. Get the number of lines:

   ```
       lines = len(self.text.get("1.0", "end").split('\n'))
   ```
2. Loop all lines, `select` from `y.0` to `y.end`:

   ```
       for idx in range(1, lines):
           self.text.tag_add('sel', '{}.0'.format(idx), '{}.end'.format(idx))
   ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***

Comment: Used this,
numLines = len(self.textBox.get("1.0", "end").split("\n"))
for i in range(1, numLines):
 self.textBox.tag_add('sel', '{}.0'.format(i), '{}.end'.format(i))

Not working

Comment: Not working in the sense, there's no change in the output. The result is the same as before selecting the whole line. `print(numLines)` gives `actual_line + 1`, i.e. if there are 6 lines then the output is `7` and yes, I'm using wrap="word" as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Please verify this single line selection: `self.textBox.tag_add('sel', '1.0', '1.end')`. I want to know *whole line* or *OK*?

Comment: I've created menu items for select all operation, from there it's selecting only the end of texts. But I was using keyboard shortcut (`Ctrl+a`, which I bind with the function `selectAllOperation`). From keyboard shortcut it's selecting the whole line. Do you have any fix for this keybord shortcut?
`rootone.bind("<Control-a>", self.selectAllOperation)
rootone.bind("<Control-A>", self.selectAllOperation)`

Comment: I'm using `.bind("<Control-a>"...` as well. So couldn't confirm this behavior. Doublecheck if you use `.bind("<Control-a>"...` for another binding?